# Send Devise Mails via Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to send `devise` mails by doing the following

**Model**

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :async, :confirmable # etc ...

end
```

**config/initializers/devise.rb:**

```
# Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
config.mailer = "Devise::Async::Proxy"
```

**config/initializers/devise_async.rb**

```
Devise::Async.setup do |config|
  config.enabled = true
  config.backend = :sidekiq
  # config.priority = 10
  config.queue = :default
end
```

When i try to sign up and as i have `confirmable` enabled i get the following error

```
ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2):
   () Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/devise-342304375946/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:115:in `send_confirmation_instructions'
   () Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/devise-342304375946/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:171:in `send_on_create_confirmation_instructions'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:228:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_create_callbacks'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_create_record'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:504:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_save_callbacks'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:120:in `save'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/validations.rb:37:in `save'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block (2 levels) in save'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block in save'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:301:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in `save'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_record_helper.rb:26:in `block in save'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/transaction.rb:848:in `with_database_metric_name'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent.rb:572:in `with_database_metric_name'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_record_helper.rb:25:in `save'
   () Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/devise-342304375946/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:17:in `create'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.5.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:815:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  meta_request (0.4.0) lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  meta_request (0.4.0) lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  bullet (5.0.0) lib/bullet/rack.rb:10:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:30:in `traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:32:in `traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  versionist (1.4.1) lib/versionist/middleware.rb:39:in `_call'
  versionist (1.4.1) lib/versionist/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  rack-contrib (1.4.0) lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:17:in `call'
  meta_request (0.4.0) lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.5.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.5.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5.2) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.0.314) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `config.enabled = true` and try again.